# Report not display in report viewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i try to show ssrsc reports in asp.net web page using report viewer

code

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ReportViewer2.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer2.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://lenovo-pc/ReportServer");
        ReportViewer2.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Project1/Report1";
        ReportViewer2.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
```

[image]

where is the probelm... and why report not display?

Answer (score 2):

It tells you the problem in the error message:

> Login failed for 'administrator'

The account that you are trying to run the report under does not have access to the database or table that `DataSource1` is trying to connect to.

Note that, for security reasons, connection credentials do not propagate when you deploy a report. You may need to set these up for that report on the server that it is deployed to.

Alternatively, you may need to [pass the appropriate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094828/user-impersonation-between-asp-net-and-ssrs) as part of your code when you run the report.